# Passing utf-8 strings between php and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, utf-8

I'm having problems passing utf-8 strings to javascript (ajax). Currently i'm using `rawurlencode` on the PHP side and `unescape` on the javascript side.

The problem is in latin and `rawurlencode` doesn't support it fully.

Is there any alternative or any better option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was in `json_encode` functions. The problems stopped when i added `JSON_HEX_APOS|JSON_HEX_QUOT`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use json_encode in PHP and receive responses as JSON (jQuery is helpful)
ajax is sent in utf-8 by default, so You just have to return utf-8

php's utf8_encode(data) gets an ISO-8859-1 string as the data argument.

need more suggestions? Tell me where You get the text from ;)

Comment: I've found mb_convert_encoding function http://www.phpbuilder.com/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php but I've never used it. I just use utf8 for all data and it works ok even if mysql has a different collation.

Answer (score 1):

From experience, Javascript's [escape()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp) (ant thus [unescape()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp)) are **not** Unicode (UTF-8) friendly. Use [encodeURIComponent()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) and [decodeURIComponent()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeURIComponent.asp) instead.

Anyway, as the docs says:

> The escape() function should not be
>   used to encode URIs.

Answer (score 0):

If php is doing the encoding and js decoding whay not simply not encode in php and encode in js as well? Not really an answer so much as a work around i guess.