# PHP array to javascript array UTF-8

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, encode

I've tried to move a php array to a javascript array.
this is what I did:

```
$cities = "בני ברק, גבעתיים, חוות שלם, רמת גן";

$php_array = explode(',', $cities);

$js_array = json_encode($php_array,JSON_HEX_APOS|JSON_HEX_QUOT);

echo "<script type='text/javascript'> var cities = ". $js_array . ";</script>";
```

for some reason, when I open the google chrome debuger, and check what cities is, this is what I get:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> var cities = ["&#1488;&#1494;&#1506;&#1511;&#1492; &#1489;&#1489;&#1504;&#1497; &#1489;&#1512;&#1511;"," &#1490;&#1489;&#1506;&#1514;&#1497;&#1497;&#1501;"," &#1495;&#1493;&#1493;&#1514; &#1513;&#1500;&#1501;"," &#1512;&#1502;&#1514; &#1490;&#1503;"];</script>
```

I don't know why it's decoding. I have php 5.6.

**Later I tried just moving a normal variable and even when I move a normal variable (without json_encode) it becomes like that**

I used those examples:

[Convert php array to Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618925/convert-php-array-to-javascript)

[Passing utf-8 strings between php and javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268804/passing-utf-8-strings-between-php-and-javascript)

Thanks!

Comment: That's how json_encode handles unicode characters...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, save your file with `UTF-8 with BOM` encoding. Then, add the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` option to your `json_encode` call.

```
$js_array = json_encode($php_array, JSON_HEX_APOS|JSON_HEX_QUOT|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: For some reason I get the same result.. The file is saved in UTF-8 with BOM

Comment: @MorHaviv Oh, it works for me... hmm, I'll keep looking.

Comment: @MorHaviv No, that should not change anything. Just in case, try pasting **[just this code](http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=4gSLLuxU)** in a new `UTF-8 with BOM` encoded php document. Then, visit it and view the source (don't use the debugger, which can sometimes modify the code received). Do you still get that problem?

Comment: It is working but now I found the thing that causes the problem. Basically the $cities var is recieved by post. I just put an example of the data can be received. `$cities=_$POST['cities'];` When I do echo $cities it looks normal, but when it goes in to json_encode it becomes decoded

Comment: @MorHaviv Well, this works for me... http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=bZUprxb6 If you still have the problem with your code, maybe giving your full page script would help, actually.

Comment: I marked you answer as correct because it is correct for the question I asked. I should have asked another question since the problem is with the post method I used. well anyways thanks to you I found the real problem and solved it! Thank you!